# Upload/ Download file securely core java in desktop application

Tags: java

I am creating a desktop application for syncing documents of my site, what should i use to fast transfer of files from client to server and vise-versa apart from using FTP client jar.

Comment: What kind of server?  It depends.

Comment: SFTP, HTTPS or SCP is popular